space of all measurable functions mapping to $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space
Is the space $\mathcal{V}=\{f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n:f \text{ measurable}\}$ (where $X$ is any set) a vector space? I would have said yes because it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication but in this thread Is the set of extended real-valued measurable functions a vector space? it says that the set of extended real valued functions does not form a vector space. So I am wondering if also $\mathcal{V}$ might fail to be a linear space?

The problem in the thread you referenced was that they considered functions with the extended reals as values. There you can face some trouble when taking scalar multiplication or differences of functions with the value $\pm \infty$ because you have to define what $\infty - \infty$ or things like $2 \cdot \infty - 1 \cdot \infty$ mean.
However, in your case the values are $\mathbb R^n$ and this means that there are no components $\pm \infty$ in the values of your functions. Then you are correct that $\mathcal V$ is a vector space, since sums and scaled versions of measurable functions are measurable again. The other properties of vector spaces are then relatively easy to prove (e.g. the function $f \equiv 0$ is the zero element of the vector space and the associative and distributive laws follow from the corresponding laws for real numbers and $\mathbb R^n$,...).
